Mailchimp Connected Sites verification of site script install
I am building a custom Marketing API integration for an ecommerce platform with the Mailchimp APIs. I am working on the Connected Sites path and ran into a road block. When hitting the "verify" endpoint (see: https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/connected-sites/verify-connected-site-script/) the response is always a 204 - no content response. I have tested by adding a domain that I do not control and does not have the Mailchimp script installed and it did not return an error and did not return a verification failed response.
The get connected site endpoint (see: https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/connected-sites/get-connected-site/) and list all connected sites endpoint (see: https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/connected-sites/list-connected-sites/) also do not list a verification status. The add endpoint (see: https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/connected-sites/add-connected-site/) does not return a verification status.
I have reached out to Mailchimp support and they were less than helpful on this lack of clarity in their documentation.
Presenting a user an action to verify a connected site with no way to tell the user if the verification was successful or any actions to take is at best a poor user experience.
Has anyone else implemented the connected sites endpoints and has guidance on how to determine verification status of a connected site?
